# How to ignore a logger in the Sentry Python SDK

Tags: python, django, sentry

I'm using `sentry-python` SDK for capture exceptions from my django server.

[image: sentry capture]

I don't want to capture `django.security.DisallowedHost` like above.
How to remove sentry handling for that logger?

I attached my server configuration below.

`settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
       'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        # Silence SuspiciousOperation.DisallowedHost exception ('Invalid
        # HTTP_HOST' header messages). Set the handler to 'null' so we don't
        # get those annoying emails.
        'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
            'handlers': ['null'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn=os.environ['SENTRY_DSN'],
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration()],
    send_default_pii=True,
    release=f"{os.environ['STAGE']}@{os.environ['VERSION']}",
)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Quick answer

See [LoggingIntegration](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/logging/), eg:

```
from sentry_sdk.integrations.logging import ignore_logger


ignore_logger("a.spammy.logger")

logger = logging.getLogger("a.spammy.logger")
logger.error("hi")  # no error sent to sentry
```

### A more elaborate but generic way to ignore events by certain characteristics

See [before_breadcrumb](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/configuration/filtering/hints/) and [before_send](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/configuration/filtering/#filtering-error-events), eg:

```
import sentry_sdk

def before_breadcrumb(crumb, hint):
    if crumb.get('category', None) == 'a.spammy.Logger':
        return None
    return crumb

def before_send(event, hint):
    if event.get('logger', None) == 'a.spammy.Logger':
        return None
    return event

sentry_sdk.init(before_breadcrumb=before_breadcrumb, before_send=before_send)
```

Comment: 1. I'm sorry for mistypo in my question. `security.DisallowedHost` is not an exception. It is logger of Django exactly. 
How can i ignore some logger in sentry with DjangoIntegration?

Comment: @kde713 I fixed my answer, please make a separate question for ignore_errors to keep this site clean

Comment: This code doesn't working. I added your code and replace `a.spammy.Logger` to `django.security.DisallowedHost`. But Invalid HTTP_HOST still sent to sentry.

Comment: Regarding the edit I just let through: That was me amending my own answer, but I forgot to log in. The shorter way does the same exact thing.

Answer (score 9):

Under the sentry_sdk I had to use the following code in before_send to get it to ignore the django.security.DisallowedHost exception.

```
def before_send(event, hint):
        """Don't log django.DisallowedHost errors in Sentry."""
        if 'log_record' in hint:
            if hint['log_record'].name == 'django.security.DisallowedHost':
                return None

        return event
```

Comment: Since ignore_logger("django.security.DisallowedHost") does not work, I had to use this method. Thanks!