# Sentry.io ignore logger dynamically

Tags: python, django, sentry

I am hoping to dynamically add loggers to a file whenever I decide to ignore a certain logger from sending to sentry, I've read the docs and this answer [How to ignore a logger in the Sentry Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52927353/how-to-ignore-a-logger-in-the-sentry-python-sdk) and I believe I got it working when I has put the literal string into the ignore_logger function.

When I try the below code, it doesn't ignore the logger, is there a better way to achieve this?

```
with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
    with open(os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..', 'sentry_ignore_logger.txt')) as f:
        for log_line in f:
            ignore_logger(log_line)
```

I had a print statement inside the loop to check it was reading the file and it printed as desired, so the issue isn't an incorrect file.
The contents of the file are:

```
django.security.DisallowedHost
```

I'm using Djano and I've put this in my settings.py after the sentry_sdk.init (I had it before it, however that also didn't work)

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you don't have leading or trailing whitespace there! maybe just do `log_line.strip()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've changed my tack on this and instead of reading a flat file which didn't work for me, I've changed the file to a json structure and loaded the string as a json object and ignored the contents from the dictionary loaded into memory.

```
with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
    with open(os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, '..', 'sentry_ignore_logger.json')) as f:
        ignore_logger_dict = json.loads(f.read())
        for logger_name in ignore_logger_dict.get('loggers'):
            ignore_logger(logger_name)
```

The file contents are:

```
{
    'loggers':
        [
            'django.security.DisallowedHost',
            'proj.module.submodule'
        ]
}
```

This seems to work for me and feels a bit more complete

Now I just need to add a new entry to that array and restart apache or the app server and the new loggers are ignored

Hope that helps